# How come my topic "What version of Windows server is needed for RemoteApp functionality?" got closed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

My topic here:
[What version of Windows server is needed for RemoteApp functionality?](https://serverfault.com/questions/446003/what-version-of-windows-server-is-needed-for-remoteapp-functionality)

Was closed as a duplicate of this:
[Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Yet, my question has NOTHING to do with licensing (I specifically removed any comments about licensing after the first moderator noted it).

Why was my topic closed?

Answer (score 3):

I have re-opened it for you since your revisions. Sometimes close votes get inertia and get closed even after the revisions.